# Python OOP: passing values between classes. objects and instances

Tags: python, oop

I'm new to OOP and it's becoming increasingly obvious that there's something fundamentally broken in my current understanding.  I wrote an example of some simple code below (using kivy objects) in order to expose my current faulty grasp of OOP.  This example programme just counts on a timer and prints it to a kivy label.

Questions:

1. The class variable *foo_counter* - it feels like I'm effectively creating a global variable (with all the messy debugging problems that entails) and this is a crutch I lean on in my real programming.
2. I want to pass values between the instances. Here I have a Clock instance and a Label instance. The Clock tells the Label to print until the Label tells the Clock to stop.  Currently, I'm calling methods like functions and just adding "self"... Because of this I'm frequently I'm finding that I'm applying the change to the wrong instance of the wrong class.

How would a proper programmer do this simple example?  To be clear, I don't care about this example, only fixing my approach.  Can you see what's wrong?

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel

class Widg(MDLabel):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Widg, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text = "Hello World"
        self.halign = "center"


class First(MDApp):

    foo_counter = 0

    def build(self):
        RepeatTimer.repeated_timer(self, is_counting=True)
        return Widg()

    def first_method(self, foo):
        First.foo_counter += foo
        self.root.text = str(First.foo_counter)
        if First.foo_counter > 30:
            RepeatTimer.repeated_timer(self, is_counting=False)

    def all_done(self):
        self.root.text = "All done"


class RepeatTimer:

    def repeated_timer(self, is_counting):
        if is_counting == True:
            self.event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.first_method, 5)
        else:
            self.event.cancel()
            First.all_done(self)


First().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. The class variable foo_counter - it feels like I'm effectively
>      creating a global variable (with all the messy debugging problems that
>      entails) and this is a crutch I lean on in my real programming.

In this example, your intuition is correct, but it's due to a bug; Here, `foo_counter` is defined as a class variable, which is shared among *all* instances of `First`.  This is indeed not much better than a global variable (except for maybe being a bit more organized).  If you were to move that into an `__init__` function and use `self.foo_counter`, that would make it an instance variable -- each instance of `First` would have its own copy.

> 2. I want to pass values between the instances. Here I have a Clock instance and a Label instance. The Clock tells the Label to print
>      until the Label tells the Clock to stop. Currently, I'm calling
>      methods like functions and just adding "self"... Because of this I'm
>      frequently I'm finding that I'm applying the change to the wrong
>      instance of the wrong class.

When you call a member function, the class instance that you call it from will be automatically passed as the first argument to the function -- this is where `self` comes from.  Therefore, `self` should always be an instance of the type that contains the method.  If you want to disable the implicit passing of `self`, you have to use the `@staticmethod` decorator.  So for example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
    def bar(self):  # 'self' is the Foo that called this method
        self.x += 1
        print('Foo.bar', self.x)
    @staticmethod
    def baz():  # No 'self'; this method is static across all instances of Foo
        print('Foo.baz')

f = Foo()

# Foo.bar('something that is not a Foo')  # ERROR - no member 'x' in type 'str'
Foo.bar(f)  # This will work, but is un-pythonic
f.bar()  # This is the most correct format

# Foo.baz(f)  # ERROR - baz takes no arguments
Foo.baz()  # Correct
f.baz()  # This will work, but is less clear
```

So now going back to your example, `def repeated_timer(self, is_counting)` is bad because `self` here is not a `RepeatTimer` but is actually a `First`.  And with that in mind, it seems that `RepeatTimer` doesn't need to exist at all -- all of its state actually belongs to `First`, and all of its operations are operating on `First`.  However if you really want to keep it separate, then you want to mark `repeated_timer` with `@staticmethod`, and rename `self` to something else for clarity.  (It will still *work* with the name `self`, but as you've seen, that will cause confusion.)

Comment: Articulate and helpful, thank you. The __init__ was out of scope in the Widg class so I added the foo_counter instance variable to the build method, I don't know if that's bad practice but it worked. On the second point, bringing the repeat_timer method into the First class as you suggested worked perfectly but it doesn't sit right with me. `self.event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.first_method, 5)` the first "self" is First surely. Am I applying the Clock instance to the First instance? My instinct was that two objects should be separate, in my mind this line should crash and it doesn't.

Comment: Kivy appears to be doing some magic behind the scenes to make `Clock` reference a single instance of some internal class (basically a Singleton if you are familiar with that pattern).  So when `schedule_interval` is processed, its `self` argument is `Clock`, *not* `self.first_method`, so it behaves as expected.